# xslt 3 regex in replace function

Tags: regex, replace, xslt-3.0

I would like to remove `'a'` or `'the'` from the beginning of a string, and `'checklist'` or `'procedures?'` from the end of a string:

input examples:

```
A Detailed procedure
The flight checklist
Takeoff procedures
```

Desired output, respectively:

```
Detailed
flight
Takeoff
```

Using a variable

```
<xsl:sequence select="replace($string, '^(a|the)\s(.*)\s(procedures?|checklist)$', '$2', 'i')" />
```

is returning the complete `$string` but

```
<xsl:sequence select="replace('A flight checklist', '^(a|the)\s(.*)\s(procedures?|checklist)$', '$2', 'i')" />
```

returns `flight` as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try `replace($string, '(^(a|the))|((procedures?|checklist)$)', '', 'i')` or perhaps `replace($string, '(^(a|the)\s)|(\s(procedures?|checklist)$)', '', 'i')`.

Comment: both worked, Martin, thank you